# Biblatex-chicago first time full citation, then shorthand (authordate)

Tags: biblatex, shorthands

I have to use `authordate` in my project, unless it's legal entries such as congressional hearings. In that case, I am supposed to reference it in full the first time, and use the shorthand afterwards. Unfortunately this does not work for me, if I use `\autocite`, I only get the shorthand. I realize I can use `\fullcite` the first time, but this would require lots of attention and is therefore prone to mistakes. I think it probably has something to do with the authordate setting, for if I use notes instead, it does work as expected. These are in general the package options:

These are the options I use for `biblatex-chicago`.

```
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,hyperref=true, cmsdate=both,sortcites, uniquename=init]{biblatex-chicago}
```

I was hoping that I am somehow overlooking an option for the preamble?
I'd appreciate any help!
Thanks!

---

EDIT

These are for example two bib entries:

```
@legislation{Congress.20180417,
 title = {Reinforcing the US--Taiwan relationship},
 series = {115th Congress (2nd)},
 subtitle = {House Hearing 115-147 before the Subcommittee on Asia and the Pacific of the Committee on Foreign Affairs House of Representatives},
 abstract = {},
 pagetotal = {75},
 shorthand = {House Hearing 115-147},
 entrysubtype = {hearing},
 date = {2018-04-17}
}


@article{Diamond2000,
 author = {Diamond, Larry and Myers, Ramon H.},
 year = {2000},
 title = {Introduction: Elections and democracy in greater China},
 url = {https://www.state.gov/communist-china-and-the-free-worlds-future/},
 pages = {365},
 pagination = {page},
 issn = {0305-7410},
 journaltitle = {The China Quarterly},
 abstract = {}}
```

and this is how I cite them

```
\begin{document}

Lalalala\footcite{Congress.20180417}, which and then later \textcite{Diamond2000} confirms, and then back to blablabla{Congress.20180417}.

\printbibliography
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Would it be possible to post a short example document that contains a 'normal' citation and a citation to a special legal entry (along with the relevant `.bib` entries of course? That way you make it much easier for others to get started helping you. I should say though that `biblatex-chicago` is an extremely complex style and it may be very, very, very difficult to modify it to produce the output you'd like to see.

Comment: Hi @moewe, I added two citations. Apologies for not getting the format correct, I hope it is still legible!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt to force `biblatex-chicago`'s `authordate` to produce full first citations for legal citations (`@legislation`, `@legal`, `@jurisdiction`).

The core of the answer is to introduce a test if this is the first citation of a legal work to the original `cite` bibmacro (which can be found in `chicago-dates-common.cbx`).

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[authordate, backend=biber, cmsdate=both, sortcites, uniquename=init]{biblatex-chicago}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\iflegaltype}{%
  \ifentrytype{legislation}
    {\@firstoftwo}
    {\ifentrytype{legal}
       {\@firstoftwo}
       {\ifentrytype{jurisdiction}}}}

\newcommand*{\iflegallongcite}{%
  \ifciteseen
    {\@secondoftwo}
    {\iflegaltype}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}%
    {\iflegallongcite
       {\usebibmacro{cite:full}}
       {\ifboolexpr{%
          togl {cms@authortitle}%
          or
          test {\iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{classical}}%
         }% Similar to notes+bib
          {\iffieldundef{shorthand}%
             {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR
                \ifentrytype{inreference}\OR
                \ifentrytype{reference}\OR
                \ifentrytype{mvreference}}% Simplified for CMS
                {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
                 \setunit{\cms@testspace}% Is this right?
                 \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}%
                {\iffieldequals{fullhash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
                   {\iffieldundef{postnote}%
                      {\setunit{\multicitedelim}}%
                      {}%
                    \usebibmacro{cite:label}}%
                   {\iffieldequals{fullhash}{\cbx@lastyear}%
                      {}%
                      {\usebibmacro{cmsbracketname}% For names in []
                       \ifthenelse{\ifentrytype{misc}\AND%
                         \iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{classical}}%
                         {\cms@testspace}{\newcunit}}% Wrong?
                    \ifthenelse{\ifentrytype{manual}\OR\ifentrytype{standard}}%
                      {\printtext[cmshyper]{\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}%
                      {\usebibmacro{cite:label}}%
                    \iffieldundef{postnote}%
                      {\savefield{fullhash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
                      {\savefield{fullhash}{\cbx@lastyear}}}}}%
             {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand+title}}}%
          {\iffieldundef{shorthand}%
             {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR
                \ifentrytype{inreference}\OR
                \ifentrytype{reference}\OR
                \ifentrytype{mvreference}}% Simplified for CMS
                {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
                 \setunit{\nameyeardelim}%cms@testspace%
                 \usebibmacro{cmscitesortdate}%
                 \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}%
                {\iffieldequals{fullhash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
                   {\iffieldundef{postnote}%
                      {\setunit{\compcitedelim}}%
                      {}%
                    \usebibmacro{cmscitesortdate}}%
                   {\iffieldequals{fullhash}{\cbx@lastyear}% Is this right?
                      {}%
                      {\usebibmacro{cmsbracketname}%
                       \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
                    \usebibmacro{cmscitesortdate}%
                    \iffieldundef{postnote}%
                      {\savefield{fullhash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
                      {\savefield{fullhash}{\cbx@lastyear}}}}}%
              {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}}}%
  \setunit{\multicitedelim}}% ???
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@legislation{Congress.20180417,
  title        = {Reinforcing the US--Taiwan relationship},
  series       = {115th Congress (2nd)},
  subtitle     = {House Hearing 115-147
                  before the Subcommittee on Asia and the Pacific
                  of the Committee on Foreign Affairs
                  House of Representatives},
  pagetotal    = {75},
  shorthand    = {House Hearing 115-147},
  entrysubtype = {hearing},
  date         = {2018-04-17},
}
@article{Diamond2000,
  author       = {Diamond, Larry and Myers, Ramon H.},
  year         = {2000},
  title        = {Introduction: Elections and democracy in greater China},
  url          = {https://www.state.gov/communist-china-and-the-free-worlds-future/},
  pages        = {365},
  pagination   = {page},
  issn         = {0305-7410},
  journaltitle = {The China Quarterly},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lalalala\footcite{Congress.20180417},
which and then later \textcite{Diamond2000} confirms,
and then back to blablabla\footcite{Congress.20180417}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: 1. Reinforcing the US–Taiwan relationship: House Hearing 115-147 before the Subcommittee on Asia and the Pacific of the Committee on Foreign Affairs House of Representatives, 115th Congress (2nd) (Apr. 17, 2018) [hereinafter House Hearing 115-147].//2. House Hearing 115-147 2018.]

Comment: Hello again! Thanks for this code! Unfortunately, I get serveral errors like this: Package etoolbox Error: Invalid boolean expression. ...nsions~\autocite[see also][]{McCourt2020}.

Comment: @SCW I cannot reproduce such an error in the code I posted. The code was only tested with the most up-to-date versions of both `biblatex` (v3.14) and `biblatex-chicago` (v2.0/v3.14). If you are using older versions, the code shown here migth not work for you. Please test if you can run the exact code I posted (without modification) without error. If the error occurs only with certain entries, please post an example of an offending entry in the question.